# pydantic setting a default value for an annotated type

Tags: python, annotations, pydantic

So I've been trying to make a class using pydantic that is created through a config json file. I've been running into an issue where I am trying to set a default value.

The basic idea is that there is a step type, that can be annotated with a "type" field:

```
from typing import Literal, Union, List

from pydantic import Field
from typing_extensions import Annotated

import pydantic

import sys


class Type1Step(pydantic.BaseModel):
    step_type: Literal["type_1"]


class Type2Step(pydantic.BaseModel):
    step_type: Literal["type_2"]


StepT = Annotated[
    Union[Type1Step, Type2Step],
    Field(discriminator="step_type"),
]


class Plan(pydantic.BaseModel):
    pre_steps: List[StepT] = ()
    post_steps: List[StepT] = ()
```

but I get this error:

E   ValueError: `Field` default cannot be set in `Annotated` for 'post_steps_0'

I think I am misunderstanding how the Annotated type works. Does anyone have any idea on what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Edit: Issue has been solved. This was a bug solved in pydantic version 1.9.1

Comment: Please add the `python` and `pydantic` versions to your question and an example to reproduce the `ValueError` that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I was using pydantic version 1.9.0

This was a bug that was fixed in pydantic version 1.9.1:

https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/4067